# JavaFX application won't launch at my friend's pc

Tags: exception, javafx, model-view-controller, fxml, thread-exceptions

I was working with my friend on a javaFX application with FXML, everything was okay till we tried to execute our work, we got that strange exception that never happened to me as far as i remember, the problem is that the same code launches normally in my pc !

This is what occures when trying to launch the code **SignatureParser.current()**, you'll find more details below

```
Thread [JavaFX Application Thread](Suspended(exception 
ArrayOutOfBoundsException))
SignatureParser.current()
SignatureParser.parseZeroOrMoreThrowsSignatures()
SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature()
SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(String)
MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).parse(String)
MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).parse(String)
MethodRepository(AbstractRepository<T>).<init>
MethodRepository(GenericDeclRepository<S>).<init>
MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).<init>
MethodRepository.<init>(String, GenericsFactory)
MethodRepository.make(String, GenericsFactory)
Method.getGenericInfo()
Method.getGenericReturnType()
BeanAdapter.getGenericType(String)
FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.add(Object)              
FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement(        
FXMLLoader$ValueElement).processEndElement()
FXMLLoader.processEndElement()
FXMLLoader.loadImpl(InputStream, Class<?>)
FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Class<?>)
FXMLLoader.load()
Main.start(Stage)
LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(AtomicBoolean, Application)
519865426.run()
PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(Runnable, CountDownLatch)
1293618474.run()
PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(Runnable)
1493066385.run()
AccessController.doPrivileged(PriviledgedAction<T>, AccessControlContext)
PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(Runnable, AccessControlContext)
156545103.run()
InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run()
WinApplication._runLoop(Runnable)
WinApplication.lambda$null$147(int, Runnable)
278934944.run()
Thread.run()
```

I have no clue where the problem is, as both of us have the same IDE (Eclipse 2018-09) and JavaFX version (8.0.192-b10), as well as scene builder (8.5.0).

**Thanks for your help !**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Hey, i've answered my question, but i need one more clarification if you don't mind, we also have jdk 11.0.1 nevertheless it didn't make a problem, but shouldn't we delete jdk 8u192 as it's an outdated version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not adding a minimal example for my problem, it turned out that **adding any javafx components to the scene would produce that problem**, but we managed to solve the problem, fortunately it was just a jdk conflict, my friend had both jdk 8u191 and 8u192 and that's what caused the problem, we solved that by **removing the older version** and voila !

Everything went normal **after restarting the pc** ofc, so the changes would take effect.

I often find the solution to my problems after posting a question here, but i hope that it would help somebody else in the future ! :)